# How to assign a command to an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Does anybody know a way to add a command to an item (emerald, stick, other ingredients), then when left or right clicked, it executes a command?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible in vanilla/unmodded Minecraft, but it's an easy task if you use mods or plugins.

Comment: While there is no generally applicable answer, there is a limited number of items where this *is* possible, using `stat.useItem` type objectives to detect the use. I believe Eggs, Enderpearls and Snowballs are "used" when thrown, and one can work from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with scoreboard but not in all cases:
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives
It's based on the stat.useItem

There is other workarounds but it's probably the more generic.

Comment: Care to give an example of code that will do what the asker wants?  Just pointing them at a link is helpful, but not very.

Answer (score -1):

If you want this on a multiplayer server then you could easily do this with a plugin. Its not possible as far as I know on vanilla without mods or plugins.